# This is completely based on logic and it was asked in the first stage of Informatics Olympiad in India. Straight logic

Tags: algorithm

1. In Gutenberg’s printing press, each line of text is assembled by placing individual metal 
   letters in a rack, applying ink to the letters and then pressing them onto paper. 
   Gutenberg needs to print N words using his printing press, one word at a time. The 
   printing press allows the following operations: 
   • Add a letter to the end of the word currently in the rack. 
   • Remove the last letter from the word currently in the rack. 
   • Print the word currently in the rack.

Initially, the rack is empty; it contains no metal letters.At the end of printing, 
Gutenberg is allowed to leave letters in the rack. Also, he is allowed to print the words 
in any order that he likes. As each operation requires time, he wants to minimize the 
total number of operations.

he could for instance, do this in 20 operations: Gutenburg is supposed to print out three words, {print, the, poem}, 
Here's the process of this

add t, add h, add e, print, remove last letter (three times), add p, add o, 
add e, add m, print, remove last letter (three times), add r, add i, add n, 
add t, print.

In each of the following cases, determine the minimum number of operations required 
to print out all the words in the set, in any order, one word at a time.

(a) {there, theirs, her, shore, three, tree, rest, hence, thorium, therefore, threshold }

(b) {problem, emblem, printer, pradeep, poland, holland, private, patrick, trick, roller, pin }

(c) {dimension, division, divide, deviation, envelope, distance, direction, direct, derive, development }

I've tried but failing every time. Answer of 1st question is 88-I'm always getting 93
2nd-120 is the answer.
3rd-115 is the answer.
I'm getting wrong every time.
Just solve one out of the three questions here and I will pick up the rest of the questions using the solution of the first-solve and show just one of them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say "I'm always getting 93". That means you have code, so show it. My first guess would be to use Levenshtein distance to find the minimum number of changes needed and figure out a 'shortest path' to print all the words. But I know that's easier said than done.

Comment: @Chrono: The only operations are adding and removing letters from the end of the rack, so it's much simpler than Levenshtein distance. Basically you just need to sort the words -- which, based on his/her result, I think the OP is already doing -- and then tweak the order a bit so you end on the longest word -- which I think is what the OP missed. (See my answer.)

Comment: @ruakh: Oh, forgot about that. Yeah that would make the number of possibilities a lot less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, once you've decided what order to print the words in, it's pretty obvious what the minimal number of operations is for that order: it's the total number of words (for the "print" operations), plus the total length of the first word you print, plus, for each other word, the number of letters that you need to remove from the end of the previous word, plus the number of letters that you need to add in order to complete the new word.

As far as deciding what order to print the words in, there are really only two ways to save operations:

- If multiple words start with the same letter, then they should all be adjacent. And within each such group, if there are multiple words that start with the same *two* letters, then *they* should all be adjacent. And so on. The simplest way to achieve this is just to put all the words in alphabetical order.
- The last word should be the longest word in the set (or tied for longest), so that you can save having to remove those letters at the end. You can do this, after sorting the words, by just selecting one of the longest words, and rearranging the groups — keeping intentionally-adjacent words together — to put it at the end. (This is straightforward to do by inspection. If you need to implement it in code, one way is to use a [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) sorting algorithm to sort them by the number of initial letters they have in common with the longest word that you've selected.)

  - From the fact that you got 93 rather than 88, I suspect that you missed this optimization? If you just alphabetized the words and left it at that, then you would end on *tree* rather than *threshold*, saving 4 letter-removals instead of 9: I note that 93 − 9 = 88 − 4.

So, for example, for *{there, theirs, her, shore, three, tree, rest, hence, thorium, therefore, threshold}* we have:

```
             letters to remove      letters to add         print!
             -----------------      --------------         ------
hence                        0                   5              1
her                          3                   1              1
rest                         3                   4              1
shore                        4                   5              1
tree                         5                   4              1
theirs                       3                   5              1
there                        3                   2              1
therefore                    0                   4              1
thorium                      7                   5              1
three                        5                   3              1
threshold                    1                   5              1
```

(where you can see that I moved the *th-* words below *tree* in order to end on *threshold*). Adding the numbers in the table, we get 88, as expected.